# Pyspark: Getting the most common value of a column?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, putty

I need to be able to get the most common value of a column using Pyspark.

In this example from the `Day` column, the result I want to get is `Monday`, since it appears more than `Tuesday` and `Wednesday`.

```
Row 1: Monday
Row 2: Tuesday
Row 3: Wednesday
Row 4: Monday
```

I figured I have to do some sort of group by and count, but the whole way the project is supposed to be done is weird to me.

Here is the example code I was given to attempt to solve this.

```
d = d.rdd
d = d.map(lambda row: (row.day.year, row.number))
print(d.take(2000))
d_maxNum = d.reduceByKey(lambda max_num, this_num: this_num if this_num > max_num else max_num)
print(d_maxNum.collect())
```

I am new to Pyspark, so the more explanation the better. I've read the documentation, but I had a hard time understanding it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

consider your dataframe name be 'd' and your wanted column be 'Day', then you should do this:

```
Day_count = d.groupby('Day').count()
Day_count.orderBy(desc('count')).take(1)
```

This code will give you mode of your 'Day' column with its occurrence time.

Comment: Is there a way to make it look more structured when it is printed. because as of this moment, it looks very chaotic.